# Implement Oauth2 as a middleware

Tags: go, redirect, oauth-2.0, middleware

I want to implement an authentication flow as a middleware for the rest APIs. The way I want to execute is:

- Call an API
- Check if the user is authenticated
- Execute/Reject call depending on the authentication status

There is no UI for the application(can use swagger UI if required). We use curl commands to execute APIs.
The problem I am facing is if I redirect the call to get the auth code then how can I come back to the previous function and carry out the operation.
For example

1. the user has called POST /writename
2. perform authentication
3. execute POST /writename if authenticated, else return an error.

In the second step, call will be redirected to the redirect URL to get the auth code(from another application). Is there a way I can return back to step 1 after getting the auth code? If not, then is it possible to pass details to redirect url so that I can execute it from callback handler? We do not store user details in our application.

Comment: You can't. The redirect is the end of the first request.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Clients are supposed to acquire an access token _before_ making requests that require authorization. How would you even construct the auth URL? You should have no way of knowing any of the parameters (client_id, scope, redirect_uri, state).